# Python - Construct a variable name based on function argument

Tags: python, function, variables

```
def my_func(arg):
    ...
    x = foo(var_arg)
    ...
```

With many variables saved as `var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3` I would be able to pass one of them based on the foo function's argument. So if I call `my_func(2)`, in the function `x` will equal the result of `foo(var_2)`. Is it possible to construct a variable name like you would with strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: Not exactly @JustinWager. The OP seems to already have the variables. They just need a good way to pair certain variables with certain options.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a dictionary for storing the variables and then dynamically constructing variable names based on the arguments passed and then accessing the corresponding values, which can then be passed on as argument to function `foo`

```
In [13]: variables = {"var_1" : 11, "var_2": 22, "var_3": 33} 
    ...:  
    ...: def my_func(arg): 
    ...:     full_var = "var_" + str(arg)
    ...:     print(variables[full_var])
    ...:     # or call foo(variables[full_var])    
In [14]: my_func(1)                                                      
11

In [15]: my_func(2)
22

In [16]: my_func(3)
33
```

Answer (score 1):

What I recommend you do is to use dictionaries. In my view, that would be the most efficient option. For example, pretend `var_1`, `var_2`, and `var_3` equal `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` respectively. You'd then write:

```
d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

def foo(var):
    return d[var]

def my_func(arg):
    x = foo(var_arg)
    return x

my_func(1) # returns: 'a'
```

As you can see, you really don't even need variables when using the dictionary. Just use the value directly.